# Deleting dateGrid data?

Tags: actionscript, flex4

How to remove datagrid data when a button is clicked, which is outside the grid.

```
[Bindable]                 
        private var ac:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection([{artist: "John", album:"AAA", price:"100.01", selected: false}, 
            {artist: "Jai", album:"BBB", price:"101.01", selected: false}, {artist: "Jack", album:"CCC", price:"110.01", selected: false}]);
        <s:DataGrid id="myDG" width="50%" height="50%" dataProvider="{ac}"
        > 

    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayCollection>

            <s:GridColumn dataField="artist" headerText="ARTIST"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="album" headerText="ALBUM"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="price" headerText="PRICE" >
                <s:itemEditor> 
                    <fx:Component> 
                        <s:ComboBoxGridItemEditor> 
                            <s:dataProvider>
                                <s:ArrayList>
                                    <fx:String>100</fx:String>
                                    <fx:String>200</fx:String>
                                    <fx:String>300</fx:String>
                                </s:ArrayList>
                            </s:dataProvider>
                        </s:ComboBoxGridItemEditor> 
                    </fx:Component> 
                </s:itemEditor>    
            </s:GridColumn>

        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

i need to have a button outside the grid.data is from dataprovider

Comment: How can the data not be part of the dataprovider? AFAIK the datagrid can only be fed data through the dataProvider property.

Comment: Agreed, unless you give us more details this question should be closed, as stated it really doesn't make sense in context of how the Flex data grid components work. Please clarify.

Comment: I think that he meant that the button is outside the datagrid, not that data is outside the dataProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{

ac.removeItemAt(myDG.selectedIndex);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         public function deletefromgrid():void {
            if (dg.selectedIndex >= 0) { 
                ac.removeItemAt(dg.selectedIndex); 
        }
        }
```